# Spring Boot Actuator Return All Metrics In One Request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Is it possible to return all the actuator's metrics data in one request? When I make a `GET` request to `/actuator/metrics` it returns a list of variables. 
I don't want to make a new request for every single variable each time.

Comment: `I don't want to make a new request for every single variable each time.` 
which variables?

Comment: You need to elaborate on what exactly you mean when you say list of variables. What do you mean when you say new request for every single list of variables ? You question isn't clear at all

Answer (score 2):

When your application is booting, It tells you which all endpoints are available, Something like this.

```
 Mapped "{[/configprops || /configprops.json],
 Mapped "{[/health || /health.json],
 Mapped "{[/beans || /beans.json],
```

These all are the endpoints avalaible in Actuator. For more you can see the documentation. Check for section Endpoints , https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/

If there is not any relevant endpoint available for your requirement, can always write a customize one.

Answer (score 1):

First, permitting the Prometheus endpoint in the configuration file (this example is with `application.yml`):

```
endpoint:
  prometheus:
    enabled: true
```

Then, you can get all the information about all the variables in one (huge) result (this example with local server):

```
http://localhost:7776/actuator/prometheus
```